# how to get part of html in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All
    
I want to get only "All" without `<ins>`

When I use `$j(this).parent().html()` I get

```
<ins class="jstree-checkbox">&nbsp;</ins>
<ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
All
```

but I need only "All" How can I get it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `.parent()` part is correct, try this:

```
var result = $j(this).parent().contents().last().text();
```

You may want to trim the result, because there will likely be white space.

```
var result = $j(this).parent().contents().last().text();

result = $j.trim(result);
```

Or if there isn't any other text, you can just do this:

```
var result = $j(this).parent().text();
```

Comment: Works with a tweak: `var result = $j(this).parent().contents().last().text();`  (http://jsfiddle.net/krLw3/)

Comment: @Pat - Thanks. :o) I caught that before my last edit. In my test code I had `.text()` on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following to get 'All'

```
obj = $(this).parent().get(0); 
var allText = obj.lastChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: andreas - Good solution. Although if you're going to take the native API route, might as well go all the way: `var allText = this.parentNode.lastChild.nodeValue;` :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
($j(this).parent().html().substring(78, $j(this).parent().html().length)
```

Any better solutions ?